# How to reference dependency version in Maven?

Tags: maven

I am trying to insert value of implementation version to manifest file, but not of current project, as you can see in my code right now (`<Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>)`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>ispf-linux</finalName>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>desktop.linux.main.Main</mainClass>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

, but this dependency version. How to do that?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>registry</groupId>
    <artifactId>desktop.common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest declaring a property for the version:

```
<properties>
    <desktop.common.version>1.0.0</desktop.common.version>
</properties>
```

Then referencing this property in both places. Here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>registry</groupId>
    <artifactId>desktop.common</artifactId>
    <version>${desktop.common.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And here:

```
<manifestEntries>
    <Implementation-Version>${desktop.common.version}</Implementation-Version>
</manifestEntries>
```

Comment: That is helpful, but it creates need to update that property manually. I use `versions:use-latest-releases` with Maven, which updates all dependencies to latest version.

Comment: @Wortig I see. However, this property approach is the only thing I am aware of being possible with maven in that regard. Sorry.

Comment: There is also `versions:update-properties`: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html